# How to override the keybindings for Emacs Org mode org-property-next-allowed-values and org-property-previous-allowed-value

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

S-RIGHT is the default keybinding for (org-property-next-allowed-values) and
S-LEFT for (org-property-previous-allowed-value) according to https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html. These keybindings are used to cycle through the TODO keywords as well as schedule dates.

I want to change the keybinding to C-RIGHT and C-LEFT, respectively so that they don't interfere with my normal editing. (I use S-LEFT, S-RIGHT for text selection).

I tried to add the following lines to my init.el:

- `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-left>") nil)`
- `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-right>") nil)`

The above 2 lines successfully disabled the 2 keybindings.

Then I added the following 2 lines to remap the keybindings:

- `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") 'org-property-previous-allowed-value)`
- `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") 'org-property-next-allowed-values)`

However, emacs (I use AquaEmacs on Mac) doesn't recognize the "org-property-previous-allowed-value" and "org-property-next-allowed-values".

I wonder what did I do wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: When you say  `... emacs doesn't recognize the "org-property-previous-allowed-value" ...`, what exactly do you mean? Did you get an error when you tried it? No error but it did not work? Where exactly did you add those `define-key` calls? If in your init file, is Org mode already loaded at that poiint? BTW, `<S-right>`  is bound to `org-shiftright` which does different things depending on context (it only calls `org-property-next-allowed-value` on a property line). Whatever key you choose to use, you might want to bind `org-shiftright` to it, if you want to keep all of the functionality.

Comment: It should be `org-property-next-allowed-value` BTW - singular, not plural.

Answer (score 0):

`<S-right>` is bound to `org-shiftright` by default, which does different things depending on context. It only does `org-property-next-allowed-value` if you cursor is on a property.

I don't know why you are having problems with the rebinding, hence my comment asking for clarification. But I thing that you probably don't want to redefine keys at all. Try adding

```el
(setq org-support-shift-select 'always)
```

to your init file instead. The doc string for `org-support-shift-select` says (among other things - you should do `C-h v org-support-shift-select RET` and read the whole thing if you decide to go this way):

> In Emacs 23, when ‘shift-select-mode’ is on, shifted cursor keys
> start selecting a region, or enlarge regions started in this way.
> In Org mode, in special contexts, these same keys are used for
> other purposes, important enough to compete with shift selection.
> Org tries to balance these needs by supporting ‘shift-select-mode’
> outside these special contexts, under control of this variable.
>
> ...
>
> If you set this variable to the symbol ‘always’, then the keys
> will not be special in headlines, property lines, item lines, and
> table cells, to make shift selection work there as well.  If this is
> what you want, you can use the following alternative commands:
> ‘C-c C-t’ and ‘C-c ,’ to change TODO state and priority,
> ‘C-u C-u C-c C-t’ can be used to switch TODO sets,
> ‘C-c -’ to cycle item bullet types,
> and properties can be edited by hand or in column view.
>
> However, when the cursor is on a timestamp, shift-cursor commands
> will still edit the time stamp - this is just too good to give up.